# Python exception text on syntax errors (boost library)

Tags: c++, python, exception, boost-python

I've got this code snnipet (the whole program compiles and links correctly):

```
...
try
{
    boost::python::exec_file(
        "myscript.py",            // this file contains a syntax error
        my_main_namespace, 
        my_local_namespace
    );
    return true;
}
catch(const boost::python::error_already_set &)
{
PyObject *ptype, *pvalue, *ptraceback;
PyErr_Fetch(&ptype, &pvalue, &ptraceback);

    // the next line crashes on syntax error
    std::string error = boost::python::extract<std::string>(pvalue);
    ...
}
```

The file that the program tries to execute has a syntax error, so an exception is thrown. When the program tries to get the error message crashes...

The code works well with run-time errors but somehow crashes with syntax errors.

How can i get the error string with this kind of errors?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation of PyErr_Fetch](http://docs.python.org/c-api/exceptions.html#PyErr_Fetch): "The value and traceback object may be NULL even when the type object is not". You should check whether pvalue is NULL or not before trying to extract the value.

```
std::string error;
if(pvalue != NULL) {
    error = boost::python::extract<std::string>(pvalue);
}
```

If you want to check whether the exception is a SyntaxError you can compare ptype against the exception types listed [here](http://docs.python.org/c-api/exceptions.html#standard-exceptions).

To answer anymore specifically I would need a backtrace from the point where it crashed.

**Edit**

pvalue is an exception object, not a str instance so you should use [PyObject_Str](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/c-api/object.html?highlight=pyobject_str#PyObject_Str) to get the string representation of the exception.

You may need to call [PyErr_NormalizeException](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/c-api/exceptions.html#PyErr_NormalizeException) first to turn pvalue into the correct exception type.

Comment: Hmmm... pvalue is not NULL, ptraceback is NULL (wich makes sense due it's a syntax error and there isn't a stack frame)